# DOM Document - How to get the text inside a tag without the inner tags

Tags: php, dom

Assume I have a dom_document containing the following html and it is put in a variable called `$dom_document`

```
<div>
  <a href='something'>some text here</a>
  I want this
</div>
```

What i would like is retrieve the text that is inside the div tag ('I want this'), but not the a tag. What i do is the following:

```
$dom_document->nodeValue;
```

Unfortunately with this statement I have the a tag in with it. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc

Comment: I've not tried it myself (so a comment instead of an answer) but I suspect you want to grab the child text nodes of the element.  If you iterate over the children and only grab the ones that are of type TEXTNODE you should be able to grab it.

Comment: You can run `strip_tags($dom_document->nodeValue)` which will give `some text here I want this`. If you want to completely remove the tag and its text, i guess, a regex would be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath for it:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);
$textNodes = $xpath->query('//div/text()');

foreach ($textNodes as $txt) {
    echo $txt->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: I already use xpath. But the result of my query contains a structutre with multiple elements an some text not in any element. Text that I need to get. So I am looking for something like nodeText (unfortunately not existing...)

Comment: @marc I can improve the answer but I'm not sure how to :)

Comment: Actually you can use xpath with any node as the starting point. Is that what you're after?

Comment: I want to avoid making multiple xpath queries. I rather would like to have one xpath query only and then use nodeValue, getAttribute, getElementsByTagName, etc... to select what I want. I have no problems selecting what I want when it is inside a specific element. But I don't know how to get what I mentionne in my initial question...

Comment: Perhaps you should expand your question with a more complex HTML and the xpath query you have so far, because to me the question as it is now has been answered :)

Comment: Ok I will create a new post detailing more clearer what I want because to me the question is not answered... Nevertheless I will give you what you want.... :)

Comment: @Marc well, what I want is a challenge ... I'll be looking forward to the next question then :)