# PHP, How to wrap parts of the text that is outside of <p> tags?

Tags: php, html

I do have some text that shows in the following way:

```
Line 1: <p>some text</p>
Line 2: some unwrapped text
Line 3: <p>some other text</p>
```

My question is how to detect that some of the text is not wrapped in < p > tags and wrap it with such?

Please note that the text might be written in one line only, and it might contain other tags than paragraphs. For example:

```
<p>some text</p> some unwrapped text <img src="..." /><p>some other text</p>
```

The desired output is:

```
<p>some text</p> <p>some unwrapped text</p> <img src="..." /><p>some other text</p>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is this text coming from? Is it only p tags you are dealing with?

Comment: What is the rule (of your second example) to determine whether the text should or not be wrapped?

Comment: @Steve I am crawling the content from another website. . i am having problems with p tags only. Otherwise the allowed tags are: p, br, img,
 and iframe.

Comment: @GabrielHeming the desired output is as follows: <p>some text</p> <p>some unwrapped text</p> <img src="..." /><p>some other text</p>

Comment: So, basically,  you need all texts inside a `p` tag if it hasn't wrapped by any other tag (and cannot wrap a `img` tag). Am I right?

Comment: @GabrielHeming yes, exactly.

Comment: I suggest an html parser, dont try and roll your own with regex, else `<p>some text</p><br>some unwrapped text<br/>` will bite you in the arse

Comment: This can start as a solution to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634526/dom-document-how-to-get-the-text-inside-a-tag-without-the-inner-tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503754/php-domdocument-wrap-all-elements-without-node-with-p

Comment: The last provided link seems to be a good start, however it encloses the img tag within p as well. thnx anyways